# First letters being erased when reading from data file c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Can someone please explain why only the first letters are being deleted when reading in from a data file but only on the 1/2/3 parts of the array and not the 0 part? (sorry really don't know how to explain it)(I'll only include part of what I am getting as well as data file)

**What i get**

GoogleyleSmith01@gmail.comyleman27ecurity question:White rabbit with a watch
Deviantartragonmaster27andalfthegreyNULL

**What it's supposed to be**

GoogleKyleSmith01@gmail.comKyleman27securityquestion:Whiterabbitwithawatch
DeviantartDragonmaster27GandalfthegreyNULL

**And the original data file**

Google;KyleSmith01@gmail.com;Kyleman27;security question:White rabbit with a watch;
Deviantart;Dragonmaster27;Gandalfthegrey; NULL;

**I won't include all of the code as it shouldn't be relevant to this issue**

```
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <string> 
#include <vector>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

const int NCOLS = 4;
const int NROWS = 10;

void description_and_options(string data[][NCOLS], int count[NCOLS]);
void available_options();
void view_line_data(int choice,string data[][NCOLS]);

int main()
{
    ifstream file_name;//create the new file
    string user_input_file;//the files name inputed by the user 
    int stringlength;
    string read_in_array[NROWS][NCOLS];
    string line;
    int counter[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    string user_option_choice;
    string small_exit = "x";
    string large_exit = "X";
    int view_choice;

    cout << "Enter the name of the input file: ";

    cin >> user_input_file;

    if (user_input_file.length() > 4)// check to see if its more than 4 in length
    {
        stringlength = user_input_file.length(); //saves length
        if (user_input_file.substr(stringlength - 4, 4) == ".txt")//checks to see if its .dat
        {
            file_name.open(user_input_file.c_str());
            if (file_name.fail())
            {
                cerr << "The file " << user_input_file << " failed to open.\n";//tells user if it fails
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        user_input_file += ".txt";//adds .dat to non .dat 
        file_name.open(user_input_file.c_str());
    }

    if (file_name.fail())
    {
        cout << "File failed to open" << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int row = 0; row <= 9; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
        {
            if (getline(file_name, line, ';'))
            {
                file_name.ignore(1, '\n');
                read_in_array[row][col] = line;
                cout << read_in_array[row][col];
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    //[updown][leftright]
    file_name.close();
```

is there anyway to fix this without completely changing the code?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but it's a bit odd that the name of the input file goes into a variable named `user_input_file`, and that the input comes from a stream named `file_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ignoring the first character because you tell it to

```
file_name.ignore(1, '\n');
```

Is going to ignore the first character in the stream after each call to `getline`.  It looks like you are doing this because you think the `;` in the file it still there.  What you need to remember about `getline` is that it discards the delimiter you use.  That means it will read until it finds a `;` and then it tosses that `;` out.  This means you do not need to ignore it since it is no longer there.

Just removing the call to `ignore` is not enough to fix the issue though.  Since you are trying to parse an entire line what we need to do is read the line into a `stringstream` and then call `getline` on the stream to get the individual parts.  This is because just reading to `;` is going to capture the newline.

A quick refactor of your code gives you something that should look like

```
for (int row = 0; row <= 9; row++)
{
    std::string temp;
    std::getline(file_name, temp)
    std::stringstream ss(temp)
    for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
    {
        if (getline(ss, line, ';'))
        {
            read_in_array[row][col] = line;
            cout << read_in_array[row][col];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrongly ifstream::ignore().

> Extracts characters from the input sequence and discards them, **until
>   either n characters have been extracted**, or one compares equal to
>   delim.

`file_name.ignore(1, '\n');` always dismiss the first letter. In your case, the first letter after ";" in line.

Answer (score 0):

`file_name.ignore(1, '\n');` will make the stream ignore one character from the input.

From reading your code:

- For what you call "the 0 part", `ignore` is not called yet before the first `getline` in the loop.
- For "parts 1/2/3", the `ignore` statement makes the stream skip the next character
- For the remaining parts, there is either a space or a '\n' that was skipped so that the readable letter was not skipped.